# Port redirection with iptables to localhost / blocking the destination port

Tags: iptables, redirect, localhost, dnat

I like to forward all traffic coming to 80 to be redirected to 8000.

I used

```
iptables -tnat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8000
```

But then port 8000 is still open to public.

I tried -DNAT:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:8000
```

But this does not work at all.
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward is set to 1.

There are no other rules configured.

Please help me out :)

--

**edit**:

In answer to the question below: Here is exaclty, what I want to achieve:

I have a service running at port 8000 which can be seen as a webserver.
It should be accessible via port 80 from outside, but not via port 8000. The internal network does not matter: may be restricted or not.

I understand, that REDIRECT does not drop packets directly addressed to port 8000, but if I would drop all packets to 8000 in INPUT chain, then the redirected packets are dropped also.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8000 -j DROP
```

Cannot work for me.

Is there a way to drop packets with destination port 8000, that have not been redirected via my PREROUTING chain?

Adding a source ip via -s does not help, right? because the source IP does not change at redirection.

**Answer**

Based on the accepted answer I could solve it this way:

```
iptables -tmangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8000 -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables -A INPUT -m mark --mark 1 -j DROP
```

Comment: You do a redirect, so the port 80 will be redirected to 8000. You are not filtering the port 8000. So add a filter rule to 8000 if you want, or add more details on your question, please !

Comment: What are you trying to achieve - it's not very clear from your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set mark in the packet you redirect. Then allow the marked packs before the blocked packs. see `iptables -j MARK -h` to mark a packet and `iptables -m mark -h` to match a pack

Comment: I know how to block a port. I need the condition on detecting that is had been redirected or not.
I will clearify my question once more.

Comment: This was a good hint, I added the complete answer above. Thanks.